# Getting historic data in RabbitMQ

Tags: rabbitmq, message-queue, spring-rabbit

I have to make a report for number of messages published to RabbitMQ and number of messages consumed by RabbitMQ in 1 day of use.
I am able to get the snapshot of statistic at some interval by using REST API provided with RabbitMQ .
**How can I get the data for 24 hours using the same REST API .**

Comment: You need messages body and attributes for the last day or statistics for the same period?

Comment: I want the number of messages published to the server and consumed by the consumer daily.